# The ambidextrous policeman problem

Tags: bayesian, model-selection

Consider an ambidextrous policeman who wants to decide with which hand he should shoot by default (right, R, or left, L).

As evidence for his decision he performs a serious of controlled experiments B1, B2, etc (e.g., a shootout in the street, in a closed space, at night, etc) to obtain likelihoods of hitting the target with a particular hand: p(B1|R) vs p(B1|L), p(B2|R) vs p(B2|L), etc.

If shooting was the only tool of his trade, and assuming the experiments to be independent, his decision would be based on evaluating:

p(R|B)/p(L|B) = [p(B|R)/p(B|L)]*[p(R)/p(L)]

with p(B|R) = p(B1|R)*p(B1|R)*... and p(B|L) = p(B1|L)*p(B1|L)*..., given a specification of prior beliefs p(R) and p(L).

However, to catch criminals the policeman has other options at his disposal besides shooting: he can call for back-up, run, drive a car, etc. To see how counter-intuitive the application of the preceding formula is consider that

p(B1|R) = 0.9, p(B1|L) = 0.8, p(B2|R) = 0.1, p(B2|L) = 0.2

In this case the likelihood ratio is 0.5625, thus suggesting that he should use the left hand. However, this result is driven by the second experiment, in which the probability of hitting is very low... hence suggesting that the policeman will do something else other than shooting if faced with that situation. But on the other hand simply ignoring experiment B2 seems too radical. The decision method should weigh the different empirical observations on the basis of how likely the policeman is to use a gun as opposed to do something else.

Can you suggest an alternative approach?

I am not a professional statistician but this problem arose in my work. I want to select a model out of a population of models which is not exhaustive, using a set of (non-controlled) empirical observations. Somehow it is necessary to weigh the observations such that those in which all models under consideration perform poorly affects the decision proportionately less than observations in which they perform well.

All help appreciated.

Comment: Questions: 1. Does the policeman have to commit to one hand or the other for all situations, or can he choose depending on the situation? 2. Does the policeman always know what situation he is in before he chooses L or R?

Comment: 1. The policeman has to commit one hand to all situations. 2. He doesn't know what situation he will be in. However, he is not forced to shoot in every occasion, he may decide to do something different altogether (running, calling for backup, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said which hand should he shoot with "by default", which I take to mean that he is going to choose one hand for all situations. In that case, he should compute his overall hit chance with each hand $P(\text{Hit}\,|\,L)$ and $P(\text{Hit}\,|\,R)$ and choose the hand that gives him the greater value. To do this, he must consider all possible situations he may encounter and estimate his hit chance in each situation, then weight it by the chance of being in that situation. Let $H \in \{L,R\}$ represent the possible hand choices, and $B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_n$ the set of all situations he may encounter. Then the policeman can compute his overall hit chances using the law of total probability:

$$P(\text{Hit}\,|\,H) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(\text{Hit}\,|\,H,B_i)P(B_i)$$

(Here I have implicitly assumed that $P(B_i\,|\,H) = P(B_i)$, that is, the policeman's probability of being in a situation is not affected by his hand choice.) Now we just use the policeman's shooting experiments to estimate the conditional hit probabilities $P(\text{Hit}\,|\,H,B_i)$, and to estimate $P(B_i)$ we do statistics on his work history to determine what situations he tends to be presented with.

It is not clear to me how it is relevant that the policeman may choose to do different things besides use a gun. What the policeman needs to know is, in those situations which he would use a gun, what is the best hand to use? We can formalize this by modifying the formula above, conditioning the events on the choice $C$ to use a gun:

$$P(\text{Hit}\,|\,H, C=\text{Gun}) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(\text{Hit}\,|\,H,B_i,C=\text{Gun})P(C=\text{Gun}\,|\,B_i)P(B_i)$$

As before, all the terms in this formula must be determined empirically either by experimentation or an examination of the policeman's work history.

At no point do I see any reason to use Bayes' rule in this problem, as you are doing in your first equation. Bayes' rule would only be needed if the policeman had not collected enough data to determine his hit probabilities in different situations, and needed to combine his experimental data with some kind of prior hunch of his accuracy in each situation.

Comment: Each of the "situations" presumably has a cost of missing the target, which might differ between, say, an open field and a city street. It might be interesting to consider those costs in this analysis, and similarly in the real-world situation faced by the OP for which the policeman's dilemma is an analogy.

Comment: Why would the cost of missing affect the hand choice? Presumably missing is bad so he wants to minimize it by choosing the most accurate hand.

Comment: True perhaps, to a first order. The costs of missing a target presumably enter in $P(C=Gun|B_i)$. But so would the probability of missing enter into the choice to use a gun. If the policeman has different probabilities of missing with L vs R in a situation with a high cost of missing but will always use the default choice regardless of the better choice for that situation, then you don't know the probability of missing in that situation until you know the default choice.

Comment: Oh, I think I see the issue; the cost of missing is another level of weighting in the problem. For example, if the cost of missing is 1000x higher in one situation than any other, and that situation comprises 10% of encounters, its weight will be 100x greater than all other situations, and the optimal hand in that situation will be the one the policeman should use (assuming he wants to minimize average loss over all situations). An encounter with an armed suspect could be such a situation... but it would be impossible to realistically conduct the relevant controlled experiments!

Comment: Exactly. No one said that being a police officer leads to easy choices. One hopes that the actual problem faced by the OP is less of a life-or-death situation. More generally, remember that there is a problem in ignoring costs/benefits also in prediction/classification schemes, as is done when one focuses solely on things like prediction accuracy or areas under ROC curves. You need to consider the costs and benefits of correct and incorrect classifications in the ultimate application of your model.

Comment: Thanks for Paul for the clean answer and to Paul and EdM for the interesting comments.